# EntiyFramework-Update composite key value in join table with TryGetObjectByKey

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I‘m using Entity framework code first ,the following  model is a join table with composite key

Model code

```
    public class Schedule
{
    public int BabyId { get; set; }
    public int VaccineId { get; set; }
    public Baby Baby   { get; set; }
    public Vaccine Vaccine { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
```

Entity framework config code

```
    public sealed class ScheduleConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Schedule>
{
    public ScheduleConfig()
    {
        HasKey(q =>
        new
        {
            q.BabyId,
            q.VaccineId
        });

        HasRequired(t => t.Baby)
            .WithMany(t => t.Schedules)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.BabyId);

        HasRequired(t => t.Vaccine)
             .WithMany(t => t.Schedules)
             .HasForeignKey(t => t.VaccineId);

        ToTable("Schedule", "dbo");

    }
}
```

the following code update tables in database

```
     public bool Update(T t)
    {
        var entityName = GetEntityName<T>();

        object originalItem;
        var key = ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.CreateEntityKey(entityName, t);
        if (((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out originalItem))
        {
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues(key.EntitySetName, t);
        }
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

The problem is when I change one of  key values ,the code inside If block in update method  never execute and the table never updates.
 My question is should I change my Model or is there any better code that can handle this problem. 
Any idea?